# MotionLayout prevents ClickListener on all Views

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I am using a MotionLayout with a scene-xml:

```
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    >
    <OnSwipe
        motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/v_top_sheet"
        motion:touchRegionId="@+id/v_top_sheet_touch_region"
        motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom"
        motion:dragDirection="dragDown" />
</Transition>
```

The 2 `ConstraintSets` are referencing only 2 View IDs: `v_notifications_container` and `v_top_sheet`.

In my Activity I want to set a normal ClickListener to one of the other Views in this MotionLayout:

```
iv_notification_status.setOnClickListener { Timber.d("Hello") }
```

This line is executed, but the ClickListener is never triggered. I searched other posts, but most of them deal with setting a ClickListener on the same View that is the `motion:touchAnchorId`. This is not the case here. The ClickListener is set to a View that is not once mentioned in the MotionLayout setup. If I remove the `app:layoutDescription` attribute, the click works.

I also tried to use `setOnTouchListener`, but it is also never called.

**How can I set a click listener within a MotionLayout?**

Comment: `<Constraint android:id="@id/iv_notification_status"> <PropertySet app:applyMotionScene="false" app:visibilityMode="ignore" /> </Constraint>` can you try dis please?

Comment: Nice approach, but unfortunately makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

small modification of @TimonNetherlands code that works on the pixel4 aswell

```kotlin
class ClickableMotionLayout: MotionLayout {
    private var mStartTime: Long = 0
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

        if ( event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
            mStartTime = event.eventTime;
        }

        if ((event?.eventTime?.minus(mStartTime)!! >= ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout()) && event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. Nor did the below answers.  However, this solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72445613/1463656) did work.

Answer (score 8):

With the help of [this great medium article](https://medium.com/@suragch/how-touch-events-are-delivered-in-android-eee3b607b038) I figured out that MotionLayout is intercepting click events even though the motion scene only contains an OnSwipe transition.

So I wrote a customized MotionLayout to only handle `ACTION_MOVE` and pass all other touch events down the View tree. Works like a charm:

```
/**
 * MotionLayout will intercept all touch events and take control over them.
 * That means that View on top of MotionLayout (i.e. children of MotionLayout) will not
 * receive touch events.
 *
 * If the motion scene uses only a onSwipe transition, all click events are intercepted nevertheless.
 * This is why we override onInterceptTouchEvent in this class and only let swipe actions be handled
 * by MotionLayout. All other actions are passed down the View tree so that possible ClickListener can
 * receive the touch/click events.
 */
class ClickableMotionLayout: MotionLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how to use this? Thanks!

Comment: And, what if i have a swipe transition on a row and a click on a button in that row? This approach would break the click transition i guess, right?

Comment: It still appears strange behavior sometimes

Comment: does @TimonNetherlands answer work? Then I would mark his answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

@muetzenflo's response is the most efficient solution I've seen so far for this problem.

However, only checking the `Event.Action` for `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` causes the `MotionLayout` to respond poorly. It is better to differentiate between movement and a single click by the use of `ViewConfiguration.TapTimeout` as the example below demonstrates.

```
public class MotionSubLayout extends MotionLayout {

    private long mStartTime = 0;

    public MotionSubLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MotionSubLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MotionSubLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
            mStartTime = event.getEventTime();
        } else if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
            if ( event.getEventTime() - mStartTime <= ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout() ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is actually never triggered with this implementation on a pixel 4 phone

Answer (score 1):

@Finn Marquardt's solution is efficient, but making a check only on `ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout()` is not 100% reliable in my opinion and for me, sometimes the click event won't trigger because the duration of the tap is greater than `getTapTimeout()` (which is only 100ms). Also Long press is not handled.

Here is my solution, using `GestureDetector`:

```kotlin
class ClickableMotionLayout : MotionLayout {
 
private var isLongPressing = false
private var compatGestureDetector : GestureDetectorCompat? = null
var gestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener? = null

init {
      setupGestureListener()
      setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
          if(isLongPressing && event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
              isPressed = false
              isLongPressing = false
              v.performClick()
          } else {
              isPressed = false
              isLongPressing = false
              compatGestureDetector?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: false
          }
      }
  }
```

Where `setupGestureListener()` is implemented like this:

```kotlin
 fun setupGestureListener(){
        gestureListener = object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
                isPressed = progress == 0f
                isLongPressing = progress == 0f
            }

            override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                isPressed = true
                performClick()
                return true
            }
        }
        compatGestureDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(context, gestureListener)
    }
```

The `GestureDetector` handles the touch event only if it's a tap or if it's a long press (and it will manually trigger the "pressed" state). Once the user lifts the finger and the touch event is actually a long press, then a click event is triggered. In any other cases, `MotionLayout` will handle the event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid none of the other answers worked for me, I don't know it's because of an update in the libarary, but I don't get an ACTION_MOVE event on the region set in `onSwipe`.

Instead, this is what worked for me in the end:

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
import androidx.core.view.children

/**
 * This MotionLayout allows handling of clicks that clash with onSwipe areas.
 */
class ClickableMotionLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : MotionLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        // Take all child views that are clickable,
        // then see if any of those have just been clicked, and intercept the touch.
        // Otherwise, let the MotionLayout handle the touch event.
        if (children.filter { it.isClickable }.any {
                it.x < event.x && it.x + it.width > event.x &&
                        it.y < event.y && it.y + it.height > event.y
            }) {
            return false
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```

Basically, when we get a touch event, we iterate over all children of the MotionLayout and see if any of them (that are clickable) were the target of the event. If so, we intercept the touch event, and otherwise we let the MotionLayout do its thing.

This allows the user to click on clickable views that clashes with the onSwipe area, while also allowing swiping even if the swipe starts on the clickable view.

Answer (score 0):

I have a tricky solution that we do not have to override and modify the `onInterceptTouchEvent` of motion layout. You simply modify that in the xml file. Hopefully it will complete @muetzenflo's solution.

If you have the motionLayout as your activity root component, then you can follow these steps.

[image]

this is the xml code solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/navi"
        android:text="@string/learn_now"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_own_image" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What happens if the button needs to have an animation as well?

Comment: @cutiko If the button is animated and put it onto your xml scene, then it will work as expected as well. You can try for imageView click listener above, it will work as well.

Answer (score -1):

To setup onClick action on the view, use:

```
android:onClick="handleAction"
```

inside the MotionLayout file, and define "handleAction" in your class.

Comment: The `android:onClick` attribute does nothing else than setting a ClickListener the way I did it. Nevertheless: I tried it and got the same result. I also tried directly binding a method in the VM `android:onClick="@{(view) -> myViewModel.test()}"`. Also no reaction